Expecting Spring Batch job to end but continued to next step
I've inherited a Spring Batch job & am trying to understand the following behavior.
An exception was thrown in the configIBMTCompletionProcessor (ConfigIBMTCompletionProcessor.java)
of the VerifyPreditErrors step, & I'm expecting the job to stop as per the step definition.
Because an exception thrown in ConfigIBMTCompletionProcessor.java should cause the afterStep() in ConfigIBMTCompletionWriter.java to return ExitStatus.NOOP. And thus the entire batch job should end.
But this step was marked as ABANDONED & proceeded to the next step IBMTFileCopy.
XML Steps Definition
        <batch:step id="VerifyPreditErrors">
            <batch:tasklet>
                <batch:chunk reader="iinnoOpReader" writer="compositeIBMTCompletionWriter" processor="configIBMTCompletionProcessor"
                    commit-interval="1">
                </batch:chunk>
            </batch:tasklet>
            <batch:next on="FAILED" to="IBMTFileCopy"/>
            <batch:next on="SUCCESS" to="IBMTFetchDataCreateReport"/>
            <batch:end on="NOOP"/>
            <batch:listeners>
                <batch:listener ref ="configIBMTCompletionWriter"></batch:listener>
            </batch:listeners>
        </batch:step>

        <batch:step id="IBMTFileCopy" >
            <batch:tasklet ref="fileCopyTasklet">
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>   

XML Beans Definition
    <bean id="compositeIBMTCompletionWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemWriter" scope="job">
        <property name="delegates">
            <list>
                <ref bean="configIBMTCompletionWriter" /> <!-- This will update the tables if no pre-edit errors, otherwise send an email -->
                <ref bean="flatFileItemWriterWrapper" /> <!-- This will create a file only if pre-edit errors are found. -->
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="configIBMTCompletionProcessor" class="com.companyName.coreconfig.batch.processor.ConfigIBMTCompletionProcessor" />

    <bean id="configIBMTCompletionWriter" class="com.companyName.coreconfig.batch.writer.IBMTCompletionWriter" scope="step">
        <property name="fileName" value="IBMT_ERR_RPT_#{jobParameters[dt]}.csv"/>
    </bean>

Java definition
configIBMTCompletionWriter bean (ConfigIBMTCompletionWriter.java)
public class ConfigIBMTCompletionWriter implements ItemWriter<List<CustomParams>>,
    StepExecutionListener {

  @Override
  public void write(List<? extends List<CustomParams>> items) throws Exception {    
  ...
  }

  @Override
  public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    logger.info("Setting the step status as: " + status);
    if (status.equals(Constants.SUCCESS)) {
      return new ExitStatus(Constants.SUCCESS);
    } else if (status.equals(Constants.FAILED)) {
      return new ExitStatus(Constants.FAILED);
    }
    return ExitStatus.NOOP;
  }

  @Override
  public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {}
}

In the logs, I can see the log from the afterStep printed:
335601  main    INFO    com.companyName.coreconfig.batch.writer.ConfigIBMTCompletionWriter  ConfigIBMTCompletionWriter.java:169 Setting the step status as: null

configIBMTCompletionProcessor bean (ConfigIBMTCompletionProcessor.java)
public class ConfigIBMTCompletionProcessor implements
    ItemProcessor<String, List<CustomParams>>, StepExecutionListener {
  // fetch data from DB
  String status = service.fetchBatchWorkStatus();

  case (status) {
    ...
    case Constants.FAILED:
      throw Exception(...);
    ...
  }
}

  @Override
  public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    // some pre-processing 
  }

  @Override
  public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
  }

Attached is a picture of the Batch job's step details:

Questions

Why did the job proceed to the IBMTFileCopy step? Even when the afterStep() method in ConfigIBMTCompletionWriter.java returned ExitStatus.NOOP.

Why is the VerifyPreditErrors step marked as ABANDONED?



managed to figure it out.
There are 2 issues:

ExitStatus of the VerifyPreditErrors step
Incorrect usage of batch:end

ExitStatus of the VerifyPreditErrors step
As the VerifyPreditErrors step has a chunks approach (implemented with a Reader, Processor & Writer), the exception thrown in the Processor (ConfigIBMTCompletionProcessor) means the Writer (ConfigIBMTCompletionWriter) does not perform its write() logic.
This causes the status variable in ConfigIBMTCompletionWriter.java to still be null. When ConfigIBMTCompletionWriter.afterStep() runs, a NullPointerException occurs & the ExitStatus (batch_step_execution.EXIT_CODE) does not get updated from FAILED to NOOP as intended
Incorrect usage of batch:end
The VerifyPreditErrors step in the job configuration (XML file) was configured as follows:
        <batch:step id="VerifyPreditErrors">
            <batch:tasklet>
                <batch:chunk reader="iinnoOpReader" writer="compositeIBMTCompletionWriter" processor="configIBMTCompletionProcessor"
                    commit-interval="1">
                </batch:chunk>
            </batch:tasklet>
            <batch:next on="FAILED" to="IBMTFileCopy"/>
            <batch:next on="SUCCESS" to="IBMTFetchDataCreateReport"/>
            <batch:end on="NOOP"/>
            <batch:listeners>
                <batch:listener ref ="configIBMTCompletionWriter"></batch:listener>
            </batch:listeners>
        </batch:step>

This means that even if the ExitStatus was correctly updated to NOOP, the Batch job will finish with a COMPLETED status, which is incorrect in the context of our business logic
